# Can process be reloaded by PID?

Tags: process

I run a daemon which cannot be restarted via init.d or service command.

Is there a way to restart a process just by passing a process id to some command?

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean? You want to restart a running process by passing the PID of that process?

Comment: yes, exactly. instead of killing a process and retyping a  command with lots of params, i'd like to restart a process just by passing it's PID (or is there something better for doing it then passing a PID?)

Comment: Ok, so is there a reason why it can't be restarted with init.d/service? If the appropriate script doesn't exist it might be better to write it.

Comment: i tried to avoid that, but for this program it seems i had to do it. thanks everyone

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Killing or Reconfiguring a Daemon without Restarting

```
kill -HUP 1721
```

Restarts the process 1721 by sending the hangup signal.

```
killall -HUP inetd
```

Causes the daemon to reload its config file by sending the hangup signal.

```
killall -1 inetd
```

Restarts inetd by sending signal number 1 which is the hangup signal.

The difference between this example and the previous one is the signal is called by name here rather than number.

Reference: http://www.comptechdoc.org/os/linux/usersguide/linux_ugprocesses.html

Comment: Certainly worth checking, but you can't depend on this behaviour for any given program.

Comment: thanks a lot for the link. it's what i've been looking for. oh, i've forgot to mention that i can reload a process like this, but it only works for programs i installed via apt (like apache, mysql). the one i compiled is not affected

Comment: It only works for those applications which explicitly setup a SIGHUP signal handler. It is not a general solution to restart processes.

Answer (score 0):

you can use the following command

```
CMD=`cat /proc/1234/cmdline |sed 's/\x0/ /g'` && kill 1234 && `$CMD` &
```

where 1234 is the process id.

What this line does is that first it copies the command line that was used to run that process into a variable, then it kills that process and restarts it using the stored command line.

**Update**: above command line has been updated

Comment: I strongly doubt you mean "&" here. Regardless, that doesn't work.

Comment: Can u plz try now. cmdline in /proc has spaces replaced with null charcters. i have added a command to replace them back. also use of '&' between commands was a typo which i have corrected